# Frontend of 10.2 Really Slow / Dropping Input

Tags: front-end, linux

I just updated from 10.0.1 to 10.2 in the hopes that it would fix an infuriating intermittent crashing issue and the frontend seems top be way slower and sometimes freezes for about a second dropping all input. I seems to be related to typing square brackets, as "123123123" will enter just fine, but "a[a]a[a]a[a]a[a]" comes out like "a[[a] a[a] aa[" even at slow typing speed, with a fresh kernel. Maybe the reason for this is that I'm a linux peasant, but is this a known bug/something fixable?

Comment: I've seen this problem with many versions on Linux, but I don't have it with 10.2 on Ubuntu 15.04.  Please don't use the bugs tag when posting questions.  The tag wiki explains why

Comment: I'm on 14.10 but I'm reluctant to upgrade just in the hope that it'll fix this.

Comment: When I had this problem, other people using the same distro said they didn't.  So upgrading might not fix it.

Comment: Well thanks anyway. I'll just amuse myself with the new plot themes until they fix it.

Comment: I wouldn't give up on trying to get an answer yet.  I don't use Linux much, but maybe someone else has a fix.